# Slicing a Hash into equal slices using Ruby

Tags: ruby

How would you slice a hash into an array of equal hash slices using ruby? Particularly something like this:

ORIGINAL HASH

```
a = {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}
```

**EDIT:** Adding answer here from below for quick reference. See below for a better explanation.

SOME CODE HERE TO SLICE INTO SAY 2 EQUAL SLICES

```
a.each_slice(2).map{|slice| Hash[slice]}
```

RESULT

```
a = [{:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:c=>3, :d=>4}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
h = {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}

p h.each_slice(2).map{|slice| Hash[slice]} # => [{:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:c=>3, :d=>4}]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a simple & elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it:

```
arr = []
a.each_slice(2) {|s| arr << Hash[s]}
```

Choose whatever value you want for the `2` above.

As a method:

```
def slice( a, n )
    arr = []
    a.each_slice(n) {|s| arr << Hash[s]}
    arr
end
```

Or simpler:

```
def slice( a, n )
    a.each_slice(n).inject([]) {|a, p| a << Hash[p]}
end
```

Comment: @newUserNameHere no worries. It illustrates some nice aspects of Ruby. steenslag caught the `map` idea, so that is indeed the most optimum solution. It just didn't come to me right off. :)